# Angular - Can't resolve all parameters when setting property in constructor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I'm trying to learn Angular2 and cannot manage to implement a basic service. I get an error that says `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for SelectListComponent:` as soon as I try to set my brandsService in the constructor. Like so..

```
constructor(public brandsService:BrandsService){}
```

Here is my code...

**Component**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BrandsService} from '../services/brands.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'select-list',
    template: `<h1>hello world</h1>`,
    styleUrls: [
        './css/app/form-elements.css'
    ],
    providers: [
        BrandsService
    ]
})

export class SelectListComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public brandsService:BrandsService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class BrandsService {
    brands = [
        {id: 1, name: "Brand One"}
    ];
}
```

Here is my **app.module.ts** code

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';    

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';    
import {BrandsService} from "./services/brands.service";
import {SelectListComponent} from './filter-list/filter-list.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SelectListComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        BrandsService
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Show your `@NgModule()` code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are including services in `providers` within `@NgModule` in your main.ts file. You can import it like this:

```
import services from './app/common/services/BrandsService';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [BrandsService, ...],
  imports: [...]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

Or import all services from an index.ts file within your services folder like this, and make sure you import `BrandsService` to that index.ts file:

main.ts

```
import services from './app/common/services';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [services, ...],
  imports: [...]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

/services/index.ts

```
import {BrandsService} from './brands.service';

export default [BrandsService];

export {BrandsService}
```

Comment: I have my @ngModule in app.module.ts and then importing it into main.ts. When adding it to the providers in app.module.ts, it doesn't resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can not user `providers` in `@Component` metadata. you have to set `providers` and declare all your compoenent in your module as below :

```
@NgModule({
  imports     : [HttpModule],
  declarations : [SelectListComponent],
  providers : [BrandsService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Remove `providers: [BrandsService]` from your component metadata.